# Where can I find the Ubuntu drivers for a Dell 1700 printer.

Tags: printing, dell, hp

I have Hewlett Packard Compaq D230 PC running Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS 32 bit.  I have a Dell 1700 printer and I want to download the corresponing drivers and utilities for it.

Could someone give me the correct link to download them?

The Dell website, only has Windows operating systems listed in their download section.

http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/uk/en/ukdhs1/Product/dell-1700n?s=dhs

Comment: Dell only supports Windows for their drivers.  You probably will have to stick with the drivers that Ubuntu has provided for you automatically.  Does the printer still work?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.linuxquestions.org/hcl/showproduct.php/product/2463/cat/myprod

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, Dell doesn't provide their own Ubuntu drivers for their printers, all those drivers are for various versions of Windows.   The printer should however run fine in Ubuntu without the drivers.

---

### Using Printers with Ubuntu

In the application System Settings (by default in the dock) there is a section called "Printing".

[image: System Settings with Printing option highlighted]

Alternatively, you can access it via the System Menu:

[image: "Printers" via the System Menu]

From that tool you can add and manage your printers.

Once you have a printer added you can manage it by right-clicking on it and choosing "Properties"

[image: Right-clicking on a printer]

From here you can see, edit and control various aspects of your printer like status, name and ink levels (if supported).

[image: A Printer Properties window]

Comment: Thanks!  I guess it'll be worth a try.  I'll post again, if I'm coming across probs.  Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

The best linux printer driver I've found for this printer is Generic PCL 6/PCL XL Printer Foomatic/ljet4.  If you have problems with slow printing I'd recommend giving it a try.

Comment: Finally I can print docs at work!

Answer (score 1):

Some configurations result in printer "escape" codes appearing in the printout as well as output that is not centered on the sheet or completely garbled output. I've had intermittent trouble with the following:

```
Generic PCL 6/PCL XL Printer Foomatic/pxlcolor (recommended)
Generic PCL 6/PCL XL Printer Foomatic/ljet4d
Generic PCL 6/PCL XL Printer Foomatic/CUPS
```

So I'm not recommending the one labelled "recommended". I'm now using:

```
Generic PCL 5e
```

This one seems to be better in my experience.

You can set this up the usual way using `System Settings` > `Printing`.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out you can use the Lexmark E230 printer driver!

I am not 100% sure why this worked but I was checking which printers used the same toner, Lexmark E230.

So this driver worked for me!

"Lexmark E230 Foomatic/pxlmono (recommended)"

Really glad this device still works for me after so many years and no longer limited to use Windows. I need to test out all the other functionality and may update this post accordingly.

I am using Linux mint 20.2 which is pretty much the same as Ubuntu.

Funny enough when you check the models online Dell 1700n and Lexmark E230 they look eerily similar! just the button placement of the dell is from the top instead of the front.

If more people can confirm this we can keep this printer alive for the prolonged future!

Comment: LM is off topic here. If you actually want to help, test your answers on Ubuntu.