# Lexmark pro205 printer

Tags: 12.04, printing

I'm trying to setup up my printer but when I search for the make and model for my Lemark Pro205 it's not showing up.  I tried to do it from the terminal but no luck either. Can you please assist me?

Comment: Is [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/179967/72212) any help?

Answer (score 1):

I have a 32-bit Ubuntu version 12.04 and I successfuly installed LEXMARK Prospect PRO 205 printer.

This is the way how.

Suppose that you allready have CUPS installed in Ubuntu (it is there by default).

Download driver from lexmark support page:
- 32-bit Postscript Printer Description (PPD) for CUPS-based and OpenOffice Printing with Debian-based packaging

Install a driver with Ubuntu software center.

Add a printer with CUPS web based administration:
"http://localhost:631/admin"