# Dell 968 All In One Photo Printer

Tags: 12.04, printing, dell

Can I get Ubuntu 12.04 to work with the Dell 968 AIO Printer.
I have a customer who wants to use Ubuntu. But i cant seem to get a driver. Can i use Wine and install the windows 7 driver.

Answer (score 0):

Dell doesnt provide drivers for Ubuntu. But Ubuntu Supports for many printers including almost all the AIO printers (no additional drivers needed). Just need to configure the printer. To configure the printer follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179957/where-can-i-find-the-ubuntu-drivers-for-a-dell-1700-printer) question.