# Driver for a Dell 964 Photo printer

Tags: dell

I have a Dell 964 photo printer that I use when running Win XP; however, 90% of time I am in Ubuntu Linux. The Dell printer does not work. I need a driver for Ubuntu Linux to continue using the Dell 964.

Answer (score 0):

As it seem's Ubuntu does not support Dell, but there is an answer in the link here [Where can I find the Ubuntu drivers for a Dell 1700 printer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179957/where-can-i-find-the-ubuntu-drivers-for-a-dell-1700-printer), try it,hope it helps.